# Woher kommt »zernegern«?

Tags: etymology, austrian

In Österreich wird *zernegern* öfters umgangssprachlich verwendet.

Dies bedeutet je nach Kontext meistens *zerstören* oder *in Stücke reißen*.

Die Frage aber ist, woher dieses Wort kommt, und ob es politisch korrekt ist?

Comment: Ich kann bestätigen, dass dieses Wort in ostösterreichischen Dialekten mit der genannten Bedeutung in Verwendung ist. Meine Edition des österreichischen Wörterbuchs hat aber keinen Eintrag dazu.

Comment: Online finden sich einige HInweise auf eine reflexive Verwendung "sich zernegern" im Sinne von "sich (vor lachen) zerkugeln". Zumindest der Autor Robert Sedlaczek ist offenbar der Meinung, dass es politisch nicht korrekt sei: http://www.wienerzeitung.at/meinungen/glossen/25419_Haben-Sie-heute-schon-gelollt.html

Comment: In seinem "Wörterbuch des Wienerischen" findet sich auch nur die reflexive form "si zernegern" (zumindest nach den Auszügen auf Goolge Books zu schließen - leider habe ich kein Exemplar davon hier).

Comment: Bist du sicher, dass das Wort nicht getürkt ist?

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann kannst du bitte erklären, was du damit meinst? Wie kann ein Wort kein Wort sein?

Comment: @user35945  Gute Frage. Wann ist ein Wort ein Wort? Ist Covfefe schon ein Wort? - Mein Scherz mit dem getürkten Zernegern war allerdings eben nur: ein Scherz; mit einer Anspielung auf die wahrscheinliche Herkunft des Wortes "getürkt" und die über Jahrhunderte recht spannenden Beziehungen zwischen dem Osmanischen Reich und dem Habsburger Reich, was uns wieder auf das Verbreitungsgebiet des "Zernegerns" zurückführt, nämlich Österreich. Doch wann ist ein Witz ein Witz? Wenn man ihn nicht zerredet.

Answer (score 5):

Ich kenne dieses Wort sehr gut, kann zur Etymologie aber leider nur sagen, dass ich wenig darüber weiß. Einen inhaltlichen Zusammenhang mit *Neger* kann ich aber mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit ausschließen.

Das Wort *Neger* ist schon seit dem 17. Jahrhundert im deutschen Sprachraum in Verwendung und bedeutet »Mensch mit dunkelbrauner bis schwarzer Hautfarbe«. Eine abwertende und rassistische Bedeutung bekam es übrigens erst im 20. Jahrhundert. Es leitet sich vom gleichbedeutenden französischen *nègre* ab, das wiederum dem spanischen *negro* entlehnt ist. *Negro* ist dort einfach nur das Wort für »schwarz« und hat einen lateinischen Ursprung (*niger*).

Das Verb *»zernegern«* hat mit bestimmten Menschengruppen oder mit einer bestimmten Farbe aber nicht das geringste zu tun.

Es ist ein Dialektwort aus der Gruppe der bayrischen Dialekte und ist somit hauptsächlich in Österreich und Bayern verbreitet. Eine Recherche im Internet hat ergeben, dass es in Wien und in der Steiermark gängig ist, was auch mit meinen persönlichen Erfahrungen übereinstimmt. Wie stark dieses Verb auch in westlichen Bundesländern verbreitet ist, entzieht sich leider meiner Kenntnis. Es scheint aber auch in Bayern verwendet zu werden, wie ein Zitat beweist (siehe Beispiele, weiter unten)

Es gibt dieses Verb in zwei Varianten:

### 1. etwas zernegern = etwas kaput machen

Das bedeutet: Etwas gewaltsam in seine Bestandteile zerlegen (also etwas zerstören), oder etwas durch unsachgemäßen Gebrauch so stark beschädigen, dass es irreparabel und somit unbrauchbar wird.

Beispiele, die ich im Netz gefunden habe:

- In einer alten Version der bayrischen Wikipedia-Grundprinzipien (vom 5. April 2008):

  > Ålle Versionen vo de Artikln bleibn g'speichert, oiso kånnst den Inhalt goa ned zamhaun oda de Wikipedia mit deiner Editierung **zernegern.**
- In einer Mitschrift einer Sitzung des steirischen Landtages vom 19. Oktober 1993. Ein Landespolitiker äußerst sich hier über die Ausdrucksweise eines anderen Politikers:

  > Ich habe in Erinnerung von *Brandstifter* bis zu den *Termiten*, das ist eine jüngste Formulierung, die ich gelesen habe, von *zerbröseln, zerfledern, ausradieren, in den Abgrund stürzen, **zernegern,*** ein Ausdruck vom Herrn Landesrat.
- In einem Blog eines Kleinflughafens in Stockerau (Niederösterreich)

  > Kurz nach den Fotos hat's bei der Schneefräse das Getriebe **zernegert,** zum Glück haben die Jungs den Pflug schon wieder repariert gehabt und so ging's flott weiter.
- In einem österreichischen Motorrad-Forum

  > Hinten hab ich den C10 mit dem roten Streifen genommen weils den nicht so schnell **zernegert.** Vorne den weichen Reifen für hartes Bremsen auf der Wiese Wald etc.

### 2. sich zernegern = laut lachen

Das ist eine Bedeutung, die im übertragenen Sinn von *»etwas zernegern«* abgeleitet ist. *»Sich zernegern«* bedeutet: So laut und heftig lachen müssen, dass man sich dadurch selbst zerstört.

Synonyme mit gleicher Bedeutung sind: *»sich abhauen«* und *»sich zerkugeln«*, die aber beide eine ähnlich unklare Etymologie haben.

Beispiele aus dem Netz:

- Leserkommentar in einer österreichischen Tageszeitung:

  > Faymann **zernegert sich** jedesmal wenn er die Oma Putz im TV sieht.

  (Werner Faymann war österreichischer Bundeskanzler, die Familie Putz ist eine Werbe-Familie eines großen österreichischen Möbelhändlers)
- Eltern in einem Babyforum über den häufig lachenden Sohn:

  > Momentan stellt er sich abends noch einmal hin und sieht mir über den Gitterrand zu wie ich das Babyphon einschalte und die Lampe abdrehe und **zernegert sich** dabei.

Comment: Schade, eigentlich hatte ich sehr gehofft, dass gerade Du etwas über die Etymologie herausfinden kannst, was es bedeutet ist ja schon klar.

Comment: @Takkat: Gerade bei jüngeren Dialektwörtern ist es extrem schwer, die Herkunft  zu ermitteln. »Etwas zernegern« wird gleich verwendet wie »etwas zerlegen« oder »etwas zerstören«. Ich kann mir vorstellen, dass jemand irgend wann mal aus Spaß eben mal ein anders Wort verwenden wollte. Aufgrund des Kontextes wurde er verstanden, anderen gefiel der neue Begriff, und so verwendeten sie ihn auch. Auf diese Weise breitete sich die Wortschöpfung aus. Aber das ist eben nur eine Vermutung.

Comment: Wieso bist du so sicher, dass *zernegern* nicht ursprünglich doch etwas mit *Neger* zu tun hat? Bloß dass die Herleitung uns derzeit nicht klar ist, beweist ja noch nicht das Gegenteil...

Comment: Die zweite Verwendung ist ähnlich zu "sich kaputtlachen".

Comment: Danke für deine wie immer umfangreiche Recherche, finde es aber auch zweifelhaft, den Zusammenhang zu Neger ohne jegliche Belege ausschließen zu können, gerade weil Neger offensichtlich schon relativ alt ist. Woher nimmst du deine starke Überzeugung?

Answer (score -1):

*»Zernegern«* halte ich aus drei Gründen für politisch unkorrekt.

**(1)** *»Neger«* ist politisch unkorrekt.

**(2)** Beim Gebrauch von *»zernegern«* anstelle von *»zerstören«* wird das negativ besetzte *»stören«* durch *»negern«* ersetzt.

> Hör auf, mich zu negern!

wäre politisch unkorrekt.

**(3)** Die Frage

> Macht *»zernegern«* im Sinne von *»zerstören«* einen politisch unkorrekten
>   Eindruck?

würden die meisten derer, die das Wort nicht kennen, bejahen.

Comment: Darf ich eine Stimme erheben gegen gedankenlose Verwendung des Begriffs 'politisch korrekt'? Etwas 'politisch korrekt' zu nennen birgt die Gefahr, sich die polemische Kritik an gesellschaftspolitischer Sprachkritik zu eigen zu machen, die mit dem Begriff 'politisch korrekt' mittlerweile einhergeht. Im Falle von *zernegern*, *Negerkuss*, aber auch (dialektal) *judala* (Kleinhandel treiben) etc. ist die Frage weniger, ob der Gebrauch 'politisch korrekt' ist. Vielmehr ist die Frage, ob der Sprecher sich des Subtextes seiner Wortwahl bewusst ist, kurz: es geht um sprachliche Sensibilität.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Keine Frage, "politisch korrekt" wird allzu oft verwendet, um Themen zu tabuisieren und Redner mundtot zu machen. In dem vorliegenden Fall aber empfinde ich eine mißbräuchliche Verwendung als überaus unpassend und verachtenswert. Man mag das "politisch inkorrekt" oder wie auch immer nennen. Die Assoziationen, die bei mir bei "zernegern" geweckt werden gehen hin zu einen Neger klatschen oder gar töten, was  erschreckend erscheint. Ich hoffe deswegen auch inständig, daß das Wort wirklich nichts damit zu tun hat, alleine ausschließen lässt es sich wohl noch nicht.

Comment: @Thomas    Ich bin nicht aus einer Gegend, wo man *zernegern* im Sprachgebrauch kennt. Aus den hier dargestellten Kontexten der Verwendung würde ich aber auf eine andere Gedankenkette zur Herleitung des Wortes schließen: nicht ein grausames Zerstückeln von Menschen dunkler Hautfarbe. Eher ein "unsachgemäßer Umgang mit Gerätschaften durch nicht ausreichend instruiertes und vorgebildetes Personal". Das hätte noch immer einen rassistischen Beigeschmack, wäre aber bei weitem nicht so brutal wie die von dir beschriebene Herleitung.

Comment: @Thomas, ist diese Herleitung deine eigene Erfindung oder ist sie gängig in einer bestimmten Region/Gemeinschaft?

Comment: @user35945 Nein, nein, keine bekannte Herleitung von mir. Weckt nur leider extrem bedenkliche Assoziationen, wenn wie hier gelesen.